# Diagnostics-Performance is not available under Windows 2008 Event Viewer

Tags: windows, viewer, events

I can see the section Microsoft-Windows-Diagnostics-Performance/Operational under Windows 7 but I couldn't find it under another machine running Windows 2008. Is there any way to enable that? Thanks.

Comment: I tried to create an event filter on my Windows 2008 Server and had the same problem. Maybe you will not find an answear.

Comment: yup, it seems like there is no answer for this. Microsoft may have removed it from Windows Server. Thanks